# Using laradock docker configuration for developing

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

Hello there we am currently developing a Laravel application. I want all my team members to work locally so we decided to use Docker for our local development environment. I did a little research and there is a project called laradock. After installing it I am supposed to go to http://localhost and the project should run. But I get this:
[image]

I am using apache2 and mysql

Answer (score 10):

### tl;dr

Go to `./laradock/.env` and search for `APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT` then edit that line to this:

```
APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/public
```

### Things to do after the change

For this change to take effect, you have to:

- Rebuild the container: `docker-compose build apache2`
- Restart the containers: `docker-compose up`

### Explanation

As mentioned by [simonvomeyser on GitHub](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1212#issuecomment-425102064) this is a recent addition which had the same effect as [rodion.arr's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850467/1494454) but this way you can leave the original config files untouched and use the `.env` file to store all your project related configurations. Obviously, since this is a docker config change, you have to rebuild and restart your container, as [rodion-arr](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1212#issuecomment-339676008) and [9bits](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1212#issuecomment-478860883) ponted it out in the same thread.

Comment: *Rebuild* is key here! I just stopped and restarted containers and didn't work. You **must** rebuild.

Comment: FYI just `docker compose up -d apache2` was enough for me, resulted in `Creating laradock_apache2_1 ... done`. This seems consistent with the [up docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/), which say _"If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation, docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted volumes)."_

Answer (score 2):

Check you apache configuration (in my case `[laradock_folder]/apache2/sites/default.apache.conf` file).

You should have `DocumentRoot /var/www/public/`.
I suppose you have `/var/www/` instead

Comment: I would recommend to change the `APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT` key to 
`/var/www/public` simply in laradock's `.env` 
`